# Any way to swap my seaborn heatmap's colormap values with its y-axis values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'm new to heatmaps and seaborn. I've been trying this for days but haven't been able to find a solution or any related threads. I think I'm setting up the problem incorrectly but would like to know if what I'm trying to do, is possible with seaborn heatmaps... or if a heatmap isn't the right graphic representation for what I want to show.

I have a .csv file of scores. It looks something like:

```
Genus,Pariaconus,Trioza,Non-members
-40,-80,-90,-300
-40.15,-80,-100,-320
,-40.17,-86,-101,-470
,-86.2,-130,-488
,,-132,-489
,,,-500
...
```

As I try to show above, the columns are different lengths. Let's say length of (the number of values in) Genus is 10, Pariaconus is 15, Trioza is 20, and Non-members is 18,000.

In addition, the columns and rows are not related to each other. Each score is individual and just falls under the column group. What I want to show with the heatmap is the range of scores that occur in each column.

I would ideally like to represent the data using a heatmap, where:

- X-axis is "Genus", "Pariaconus", "Trioza", "Non-members".
- Y-axis is
  range of scores that occur in the dataset. In the example above,
  Y-axis values would go from -40 to -500.
- Colorbar is the
  **normalized population** of the columns that get that score in
  the Y-axis. For example, if 100% of the Genus column scores around
  -40, that area in Y-axis would be colored red (for 1.0). The remainder of the y-axis for Genus would be colored blue (for 0.0),
  because no scores for Genus are in the range -50 to -500. For the
  purposes of my project, I'd like to show that the majority of scores
  of "Genus" fall in a certain range, "Pariaconus" in another range,
  "Non-members" in another range, and so on.

The reason I want to represent this with a heatmap and not, say, a line graph is because line graphs would suggest that there is a trend between rows in the same column. In the example above (Genus column), a line/scatter graph would make it seem that there's a relationship between the score -40, -41, and -45 as you move down the X-axis. In contrast, I just want to show the range of scores in each column.

With the data in the .csv format above, right now I have the following heatmap: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glo7v.jpg

I get this with the line of code:

```
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="coolwarm")
```

In this heatmap, the values of the Y-axis are automatically set as the row indices from the .csv file, and the colormap values are the scores (values of the rows).

If I could just figure out how to swap the colormap and the Y-axis, then I hope that I could then move on to figuring out how to normalize the populations of each column instead of having it as the raw indices: 0 to 18000. But I've been trying to do this for days and haven't come close to what I want.

Ideally, I would want something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcVD7.jpg. Of course, in the heatmap, there would be gradients instead of solid colors.

If anyone can answer, I had these questions:

1. Is what I'm trying to do achievable/is this something I can do with
   a heatmap? Or should I be using a different representation?
2. Is this possibly a problem with how my input data is represented? If so, what is the correct representation when building a heatmap like this?

Any other guidance would be super appreciated.

Comment: As you are trying to visualize the *distribution* of your data, I would recommend another visualization. Why don't you try how [a boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html?highlight=boxplot#seaborn.boxplot) looks?


Another good visualization could be a [distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html?highlight=distplot#seaborn.distplot) coupled to a pairgrid.

Comment: @cripcate Thank you so much! These both look great; I'll experiment with both. I really appreciate it!